Powershell script: Loop over executables
I want to run a pretty basic script that has a list of executables (different python versions in this case) that runs them one by one in a loop as part of a command.
Example:
$py39 = python # can be full path to an .exe if needed
$py310 = python3.10
$py311 = python3.11
$pythons = $py39,$py310,$py311

Foreach ($py in $pythons)
{

$py --version

$py -c "print('hello world')"

}

"python", "python3.10", "python3.11" all launch their respective python version when I run it myself correctly.
When I run the script I get these errors. How do I make it work?
+ $py --version
+       ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'version' in expression or statement.

+ $py -c "print('hello world')"
+     ~~
Unexpected token '-c' in expression or statement.


This question is similar to: how to execute an exe with variable value for path and arguments. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need the & operator to run it as a system command rather than a ps expression I guess:
$py39 = "python"      # Full path to the executable if needed
$py310 = "python3.10"
$py311 = "python3.11"
$pythons = $py39, $py310, $py311

foreach ($py in $pythons) {
    & $py --version          # Use the & operator to run the command
    & $py -c "print('hello world')"  # Same here for -c
}


On a side note I suggest uswing more meaningful names expliciting when a variable is a collection and when its an element of a collection: foreach($PythonExe in $PythonPit) is much easier to understand IMHO

It might be good to check to see if the command is available in the path. Get-Command -Name $py; if (-not $?) { Write-Host 'Command $py not found.' }
